# Non-readable POM in jenkins pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, devops

I am trying to build a maven project through pipeline getting the below error in build stage.

```
 Non-readable POM /var/jenkins_home/workspace/<Main-job-folder>/<project-folder>/<job-name>/pom.xml: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/<Main-job-folder>/<project-folder>/<job-name>/pom.xml (No such file or directory)
```

How can I eliminate this error??

Comment: As the error stated the pom.xml is not there? Anything else is unclear because no context given...

Comment: POM is there in root folder itself

Comment: sh "${mvnCMD} -s ${MAVEN_SETTINGS} -f ${workspace}/<project-name-gitlab>/pom.xml clean package -Dbranch=${branch_name} -DbuildId=$BUILD_ID -DskipTests"

Comment: How can I locate the POM? Is there a way?

Comment: Why using shell call in Pipeline? Second why using `-f ...` and why `-Dbranch=` ? Use a multi branch pipeline... Use Tool Installation in Jenkins and use `withMaven(...) { sh 'mvn clena package.' }`  ...  https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven/